# Distance Variable with unequal intervals

Tags: regression

Suppose that $x$ takes the following values:  0 feet from start, 10 feet from start, and 15 feet from start. Let the outcome variable be $y$. How would you interpret the regression coefficient of $x$ ($\beta_1$) in a linear regression? Would it be: a unit increase in $x$ is associated with an expected increase of $\beta_1$ in $y$? It seems that this would be a problem because a unit could be an increase from $x=0$ to $x=10$ or an increase from $x=10$ to $x=15$.

Comment: A "unit," by definition, is $1$.  Thus it would be one-tenth the change from $x=0$ to $x=10$ or one-fifth the change from $x=10$ to $x=15$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If x is coded with 0, 10 and 15, then no: the coefficient would be interpreted as a *one unit* (i.e. 1-foot) increase in $x$ is associated with a Blah-Dee-Blah unit change in $y$.

However, if $x$ is coded 0, 1, 2 (i.e. ordinally), then you've got some problems.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is coded in 'feet from start' there's no problem, the coefficient of $x$ is in  per foot from start.

If you have it coded in some other fashion (0,1,2, or 1,2,3, or -1,0,1) say, it *doesn't* represent an interval scale but a set of ordinal categories. If those are treated appropriately, then you still don't have a problem, though you'll have two coefficients, not one. How they're interpreted depends on how you wrote your model.

So how is $x$ coded?